# Slow iOS string operation...why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I have four textfields from which I need to create a "name" as follows:

firsname lastname and otherfirstname otherlastname  (i.e. Barbara Smith and John Jameson)

But if any part is missing it needs to be left out along with either the separating space(s) and/or the separating "and" so it could end up 'Barbara and John' or 'John Jameson' or 'Smith and Jameson' or whatever combination of those four fields exists.

I call a method to create this new name string from `textFieldShouldEndEditing` if it's one of these four fields performing the callback.  I then use my own protocol method to set the app title through a delegate callback (due to my view controller nesting).

This all works great, except that for some reason, tapping between these four fields is really slow.

Tapping between any other textfields in my view is much faster.  I suspect it's my name string generation method.

Here is my `textFieldShouldEndEding` callback:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
// set the event title if the client name fields have been edited
if ((textField == self.CPNameFirst) || (textField == self.CPNameLast) || (textField == self.CSNameFirst) || (textField == self.CSNameLast)) {
    if (self.CPNameFirst.text.length == 0 && self.CPNameLast.text.length == 0 && self.CSNameFirst.text.length == 0 && self.CSNameLast.text.length == 0) {
        // the user has just erased all data that could make up the event name automatically
        self.theEvent.name = @"New Client";
    } else {
        // set the event name using the client names
        self.theEvent.name = [self generateAutomaticEventName];
    }
    [self.delegate changeAppTitle:self.theEvent.name];
}
return YES;
}
```

And the method to generate the name string:

```
- (NSString *)generateAutomaticEventName {
NSString *theName = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *CPPart = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *CSPart = [[NSString alloc] init];

// generate the primary client part
if ((self.CPNameFirst.text.length == 0) && !(self.CPNameLast.text.length == 0)) {
    // primary first name is blank so we don't need the leading space
    CPPart = self.CPNameLast.text;
} else if ((self.CPNameLast.text.length == 0) && !(self.CPNameFirst.text.length == 0)) {
    // primary first name is blank so we don't need the trailing space
    CPPart = self.CPNameFirst.text;
} else if ((self.CPNameFirst.text.length == 0) && (self.CPNameLast.text.length == 0)) {
    // both are blank
    CPPart = @"";
} else {
    // neither are blank
    CPPart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.CPNameFirst.text, self.CPNameLast.text];
}

// generate the secondary client part
if ((self.CSNameFirst.text.length == 0) && !(self.CSNameLast.text.length == 0)) {
    // secondary first name is blank so we don't need the leading space
    CSPart = self.CSNameLast.text;
} else if ((self.CSNameLast.text.length == 0) && !(self.CSNameFirst.text.length == 0)) {
    // secondary first name is blank so we don't need the trailing space
    CSPart = self.CSNameFirst.text;
} else if ((self.CSNameFirst.text.length == 0) && (self.CSNameLast.text.length == 0)) {
    // both are blank
    CSPart = @"";
} else {
    // neither are blank
    CSPart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.CSNameFirst.text, self.CSNameLast.text];
}

// combine the two parts into the final name
if ((CSPart.length == 0) && !(CPPart.length == 0)) {
    // no secondary client names entered
    theName = CPPart;
} else if ((CPPart.length == 0) && !(CSPart.length == 0)) {
    // no primary client names entered
    theName = CSPart;
} else if ((CPPart.length == 0) && (CSPart.length == 0)) {
    // both are blank
    theName = @"New Client";
} else {
    theName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@", CPPart, CSPart];
}

return theName;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Could it be something else causing the slowdown?  (It's not the delegate callback to set the app title...I've already tested that.)

Comment: Might be a question better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried using the instruments time profiler? That should be able to tell you what operations are causing the lag. Also, there's no need to `alloc` and `init` your NSStrings since you're just assigning them right after.

Comment: this is really not fun code to look at... maybe just set a BOOL at the top for lastNameIsSet and firstNameIsSet or similar. `!(CSPart.length == 0)`is too many reverses to be readable, my brain goes length, no zero length, no not zero length... that is the same as `if(CSPart.length)`

Comment: Grady - good point.  I'll clean it up.  However, although ugly (admittedly) it's accurate, and the iPad can read it much faster than us.  But why is there a noticeable lag when tapping between fields?  This should really execute instantly, no?

Comment: JJC - When I Time Profile it, it doesn't drill down past the call to generateAutomaticName (which it marks as 100% of time spent executing textFieldShouldEndEditing).  Maybe I'm just not good enough with the profiler to figure out how to drill down to my function to see how IT times out.  I guess I'll keep messing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't solve this.  I cleaned up my code a lot and it still executes terribly slowly when called from `textFieldShouldEndEditing`.

I put the call in `textFieldShouldReturn` and `keyboardWillBeHidden` instead and it's all much faster now (though it executes only when the keyboard is closed or Return is tapped).

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As one of the commenter's mentioned, Instruments is your friend. You can run your app with Instruments by selecting "Profile" under the "Product" menu in Xcode. Use the Time Profiler template.

Some obvious issues just glancing at your code:

- Don't alloc/init CPPart and CSPart. You are going to assign them later. (Convention says local variables like these should start lower case.)
- You calculate the length of each text field 3 times. Just do it once and store in a local variable.

My guesses like everyone else's are just guesses. Profiling with Instruments will tell you exactly where time is being spent.

Comment: Trying to figure it out with Time Profiler, but I can't figure out how to drill down to the `generateAutomaticEventName` method.  I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: Also, I should have named the variables theCPPart and theCSPart I guess.  You're right about the naming convention.  And I've now removed the alloc/init.  I have no clue why I put those in there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but anyway this is a little optimization.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.CPNameFirst.text, ... all your inputs..., nil];
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString *s in array)
{
    if (s.length>0)
    {
        if (str.length>0)
            [str appendString:@" "];
        [str appendString:s];
    }
}
if (!str.length)
    str = @"new client";
return str;
```

(There might be some syntax errors because I didn't test this.)

Comment: the code looks fine? or there isn't an error that is obviously detected?

Comment: @GradyPlayer Well, I don't see any real bottleneck in the original code, specially with today's processors. :)

Comment: well there isn't a loop, so I don't know why it would be slow, and I suspect that it isn't. it will just run in constant time, but it is still not pleasant.

Comment: Looping like this won't exactly work though.  I need to insert the word 'and' between the first two parts (or first 1 or none) and the second two parts (or send single part) or leave it out if there's no seconds parts at all.  That's why I ended up breaking it right down to silly "if" statements.  Still, maybe I can do something like two chunks like this and stick the "and" in if there's anything in the second part.

Comment: Oh, and like I said in other comments:  I know this code is ugly but it should still run instantly on an iPad Air.  Yet, it's lagging a bit when I tap between fields.  I don't get it.  Unless maybe, just maybe, all these "if" statements are troublesome.  Argh.